# Discord.js Logging, How to send a question to a specific channel with embed?

Tags: javascript, logging, discord, discord.js, audit-logging

Im trying to set up some moderation logging for my bot, but cant figure out how to send a deleted message to a logs channel, only to the same channel it was deleted from.

Here is my code (sorry if its messy, im new):

In my main.js:
`` client.on("messageDelete", message => require(`./Logging Items/messagedelete.js`)(message)) ``

In my messagedelete.js: `` module.exports = message => message.channel.send(`"${message}" was deleted by ${message.author}`); ``

^ This is the working code!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by ID Using [GuildChannelManager#](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager)[cache#get()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)
example:

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(id);
channel.send(content);
```

or using [GuildChannelManager#](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager)[cache#find()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)
example:

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel=> channel.name === "ChannelName"); //cAsE sEnSeTiVE
channel.send(content);
```